# iOS: Can I tell a UIView to drop its CALayer?

Tags: ios

I'm short on RAM most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should rethink your app logic if you are piling up views like that.  However have you tried setting the bottom views hidden property to YES?

Comment: Is there any concrete evidence that setting a view's hidden property to YES will free up the CALayer's pixel memory? I mean, has anyone tested the hypothesis?

Answer (score 0):

If its not visible, remove it from the superview, if you are so tight on RAM.

However, I can't see why you are in a state with multiple seemingly-memory-heavy stacked views in the first place.